# Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client with mongoose and node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, mongoose

I'm trying to make a registration function for users. I want to check first if the email exist, if so return a json

```
{ message: 'cannot register a new user' }
```

or else a json with confirmation and registered user details.

this code works fine, however the compiler says:

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

its seems the the problem is this line:

```
res.status(200).json({ message: 'A new user was created!', user: result });
```

but I don't know how fix it so it won't make this message

my code is:

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const User = require('../models/user');

exports.signup = async (req, res, next) => {
    const firstname = req.body.firstname;
    const lastname = req.body.lastname;
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;

    try {
        let canRegister = await User.findOne({ email: email })
            .then(user => {
                if (!user) {
                    return true;
                }
                res.status(400).json({ message: 'Email is already in use' });
            })
            .catch(err => {
                if (!err.statusCode) {
                    err.statusCode = 500;
                }
                next(err);
            });

        let addUser = await bcrypt
            .hash(password, 12)
            .then(hashedPw => {
                const user = new User({
                    firstname: firstname,
                    lastname: lastname,
                    email: email,
                    password: hashedPw
                });
                return user.save();
            })
            .then(result => {
                res.status(200).json({ message: 'A new user was created!', user: result });
            })
            .catch(err => {
                if (!err.statusCode) {
                    err.statusCode = 500;
                }
                next(err);
            });
    } catch {
        res.status(400).json({ message: 'Email is already in use' });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to send the response twice.

```
let canRegister = await User.findOne({ email: email })
            .then(user => {
                if (!user) {
                    return true;
                }

                // You might have executed this 1st - and continue.
                res.status(400).json({ message: 'Email is already in use' });
            })
            .catch(err => {
                if (!err.statusCode) {
                    err.statusCode = 500;
                }
                next(err);
            });
```

**But your code doesn't exit. It moves onto the next block.**

```
let addUser = await bcrypt
            .hash(password, 12)
            .then(hashedPw => {
                const user = new User({
                    firstname: firstname,
                    lastname: lastname,
                    email: email,
                    password: hashedPw
                });
                return user.save();
            })
            .then(result => {
                // Then you are sending status again with this line.
                res.status(200).json({ message: 'A new user was created!', user: result });
            })
            .catch(err => {
                if (!err.statusCode) {
                    err.statusCode = 500;
                }
                next(err);
            });
```

You should figure out after `canRegister` is assigned (await block is complete) and return appropriately before proceeding to the next block.

Something like this:

```
let canRegister = await User.findOne({ email: email })
            .then(user => {
                if (!user) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;

                // Don't use the res.status here.
            })
            .catch(err => {
                if (!err.statusCode) {
                    err.statusCode = 500;
                }
                next(err);
            });

if (!canRegister) {
     return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Email is already in use' });
}
```

Comment: Cheers @Karina Do you mind accepting this as an answer - would appreciate the green tick!